# Is there an isomorphism of additive groups between $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that I have to study the order of every element in $\mathbb{Q/Z}$.
But what do I do?
I've been struggling of what to do for this question

Comment: So what can you say about the order of every element in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}$ has no torsion elements, while $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ is a torsion group. This means that they cannot be isomorphic groups.

Comment: I don't believe that $Q/Z$ is isomorphic to $Q$, except perhaps as sets; as additive groups, they're certainly not isomorphic, because every nonzero element of $Q$ has infinite order, while the element $[1/2]$ in $Q/Z$ has order 2.

Comment: But, interestingly, $\mathbb R$ is isomorphic to  $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$, if you accept the axiom of choice.

Comment: Every element in G,  G=Q/Z has finite order

Answer (score 6):

The abelian group $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is torsion-free, but the abelian group
 $(\mathbb{Q/Z},+)$ is not torsion-free. Hence these two groups cannot be isomorphic. Also, the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Q}$ is flat, whereas $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ is not flat.

Answer (score 5):

In the group $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ we have the element $\frac 12+\mathbb Z$ which is of order two. But non of the elements of additive group $\mathbb Q$ is of order two. This shows that there is no such isomorphism.