# A question about a proof of $\operatorname{ord}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})<\infty$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $r+\mathbb{Z}$ be some coset of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, where $r\in\mathbb{Q}$, thus we can write $r$ as ratio $\frac{m}{n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Then $n$ times $r+\mathbb{Z}$ is $n(r+\mathbb{Z})=m+n\mathbb{Z}=m+\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$.

The above is part of a proof of the basic claim, that $\operatorname{ord}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})<\infty$.

The thing that I'm not sure with it is why $n\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$; perhaps because they isomorphic, and that is enough?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\mathrm{ord}$? There are certainly infinitely many elements in both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, and there are elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ of arbitrarily large order... Also, where are you reading this proof in - a textbook, course notes, what?

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic. To do so, I realize that it would be easy to prove that the order of a coset $X\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is finite, while the order of any rational(that not zero) is infinite.

Comment: They cannot be isomorphic because (for instance) $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is torsion while $\Bbb Q$ is torsion-free.

Comment: @AdLibitum, I didn't get to the idea of torsion yet. But, I know that there are several ways of showing that.

Comment: This has been explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254189/is-there-an-isomorphism-of-additive-groups-when-mathbbq-z-isomorphic-to-m).

Comment: I'm not sure $\text{ord}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})<\infty$ can be given a meaning. The group is infinite (being divisible); every *element* has finite order, but there's no bound on the order of elements, because $\frac{1}{n}+\mathbb{Z}$ has order $n$ (for $n>0$ a natural number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a group $G$ and a normal subgroup $H$, remember that the group operation on $G/H$ is defined by
$$(g_1H)(g_2H)=(g_1g_2)H$$
Therefore the group operation on $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is
$$(r_1+\mathbb{Z})+(r_2+\mathbb{Z})=(r_1+r_2)+\mathbb{Z}$$
In particular, in your situation with $r=\frac{m}{n}$ with $n$ a positive integer,
$$n\cdot (r+\mathbb{Z})=\underbrace{(r+\mathbb{Z})+\cdots+(r+\mathbb{Z})}_{n\text{ times}}=(n\cdot r)+\mathbb{Z}=m+\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$$
I'd say the $n\mathbb{Z}$ was just a typo.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The equality $n+\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$ (which is what I assume you meant) is an equality as cosets, not as groups. 
since $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, in the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ the equality $n+\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$ holds.